# How to avoid overfitting with imbalanced data?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am working on a classifier for binary classification. The data is imbalanced with class 0 of of 83.41% and class 1 of 16.59%. I am using Mathews Correlation coefficient to evaluate the performance of the classifier. Also note that the data is quite less with dimension ((211, 800)).

I am using Logistic regression to address the problem. I used GridSearchCV for hyper parameter optimisation and came up with the following best hyper parameter values :

Best Params: {'C': 1000, 'class_weight': {1: 0.83, 0: 0.17000000000000004}, 'penalty': 'l1', 'solver': 'liblinear'}

Best MCC 0.7045053547679334

I plotted the validation curve over a range of C values to check wether the model is overfitting/underfitting.

```
train_scores, test_scores = validation_curve(LogisticRegression(penalty='l1',
                                                                solver='liblinear',
                                                                class_weight={1: 0.83, 0: 0.17000000000000004}),
                                             X, y,'C', C, cv=5, scoring=make_scorer(matthews_corrcoef))
train_scores_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis=1)
train_scores_std = np.std(train_scores, axis=1)
test_scores_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis=1)
test_scores_std = np.std(test_scores, axis=1)

plt.title("Validation Curve with Logistic Regression")
plt.xlabel("C")
plt.ylabel("MCC")
plt.ylim(0.0, 1.1)
lw = 2
plt.semilogx(C, train_scores_mean, label="Training score",
             color="darkorange", lw=lw)
plt.fill_between(C, train_scores_mean - train_scores_std,
                 train_scores_mean + train_scores_std, alpha=0.2,
                 color="darkorange", lw=lw)
plt.semilogx(C, test_scores_mean, label="Cross-validation score",
             color="navy", lw=lw)
plt.fill_between(C, test_scores_mean - test_scores_std,
                 test_scores_mean + test_scores_std, alpha=0.2,
                 color="navy", lw=lw)
plt.legend(loc="best")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Based on my understanding seeing this curve it shows that the model tends to overfit as it performs low on validation set and high on training set. Could anyone point me into some direction as how to address this on such a small dataset.

Comment: https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 0):

You could do a number of things:

1. Use [SMOTE](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html) to oversample the minority class.
2. Reduce the number of iterations of GridSearchCV or use RandomSearchCV.

Comment: Since after SMOTE the classes would eventually be balanced should I still fo with MCC or switch to any other metric ?

Comment: You could use [ROC AUC](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-auc-roc-curve-68b2303cc9c5)